# How to read all splitcontainers and i

Tags: c#

Hi 
I have 50 splitcontainers.. i want to read all the splitcontainers & its panels programmatically...Is it possible...?

Because the below code only reads Splitcontainer4 & Panel1, But Iam looking to read all the splitcontainers and its panels programmatically...

```
foreach (Control Ctrl in this.splitContainer4.Panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (Ctrl is RichTextBox)
                {
                    ((RichTextBox)(Ctrl)).KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.Common_KeyPress);
                }
            }
```

Thanks for ideas...

Regards
PARAMU

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094410/how-to-read-richtextbox-controls-inside-all-splitcontainers

Answer (score 1):

Find all the splitcontainers [see SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-winform-of-a-specific-type-button-textbox) and check both panels for the desired controls.