# Enable and Disable buttons, labels based on some conditions

Tags: c#, winforms, button, label

I have 5 buttons and 5 labels next to each button. When i run the app i expect the first button to be enabled and the the rest disabled and greyed out with the labels. after i click the first button it should disable with the label and enable the second button, and so forth with all the other buttons.

this way is to long, is there a better way of doing this?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        btn1.Enabled = true;
        btn2.Enabled = false;
        btn3.Enabled = false;
        btn4.Enabled = false;
        btn5.Enabled = false;
        lblStep1.Enabled = true;
        lblStep2.Enabled = false;
        lblStep3.Enabled = false;
        lblStep4.Enabled = false;
        lblStep5.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            btn1.Enabled = false;
            btn2.Enabled = true;
            btn3.Enabled = false;
            btn4.Enabled = false;
            btn5.Enabled = false;
            lblStep1.Enabled = false;
            lblStep2.Enabled = true;
            lblStep3.Enabled = false;
            lblStep4.Enabled = false;
            lblStep5.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            btn1.Enabled = false;
            btn2.Enabled = false;
            btn3.Enabled = true;
            btn4.Enabled = false;
            btn5.Enabled = false;
            lblStep1.Enabled = false;
            lblStep2.Enabled = false;
            lblStep3.Enabled = true;
            lblStep4.Enabled = false;
            lblStep5.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn1.Enabled = false;
        btn2.Enabled = false;
        btn3.Enabled = false;
        btn4.Enabled = true;
        btn5.Enabled = false;
        lblStep1.Enabled = false;
        lblStep2.Enabled = false;
        lblStep3.Enabled = false;
        lblStep4.Enabled = true;
        lblStep5.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn1.Enabled = false;
        btn2.Enabled = false;
        btn3.Enabled = false;
        btn4.Enabled = false;
        btn5.Enabled = true;
        lblStep1.Enabled = false;
        lblStep2.Enabled = false;
        lblStep3.Enabled = false;
        lblStep4.Enabled = false;
        lblStep5.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn1.Enabled = true;
        btn2.Enabled = false;
        btn3.Enabled = false;
        btn4.Enabled = false;
        btn5.Enabled = false;
        lblStep1.Enabled = true;
        lblStep2.Enabled = false;
        lblStep3.Enabled = false;
        lblStep4.Enabled = false;
        lblStep5.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Create a `bool` method or just method. Then slap that err.. call the method on each button to somehow shorten the code.

Comment: in looping through your controls this link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545775/how-to-loop-through-all-controls-in-a-windows-forms-form-or-how-to-find-if-a-par

Comment: If the controls are related in logic there should be some data structure(eg. List<Button>) to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let all these buttons and labels are inside a container(if it doesn't mean that you can use this.Controls as well if the form contains these buttons and labels only). Let it be `pnlContainer`, Now you can try something like this:

```
public void ButtonController(Button buttonToEnable, Label labelToenable)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl == buttonToEnable || ctrl == labelToenable)
        {
            ctrl.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ctrl.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So in `Form1_Load`  you want to enable `btn1` and `lblStep1` so the call should be :

```
ButtonController(btn1,lblStep1);
```

For `btn1_Click` the method call will be like `ButtonController(btn2,lblStep2);`. in short, you can pass the button and label that you want to enable to this method, which will disable rest of controls in the container.