# C# Combobox dropdownlist item type

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, drop-down-menu, oftype

I have a form with sixteen combo-boxes, each with the `DropDownStyle` property set to `DropDownList`. I am trying to set the form so each control shows its first pre-defined value:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ComboBox DropDown in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
            DropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

This code is not working, although individually assigning each item does. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is interesting. Are you sure that `this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>` actually returns the list of comboboxes? Try debugging it - do you, in fact, get the 16 controls you expect?

Comment: Now that I think about it, actually, isn't this something that can be set at design-time? Why do you need this to be set in `Form_Load`?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan It doesn't appear to be, and I have no idea why... (I'm not overly experienced with C#.) "Enumeration yielded no results" is the message I see.

Comment: Try wrapping the code with Catch/Try block.

Comment: Ok, that's a start. My WinForms are a bit rusty, but if I remember correctly, `this.Controls` will only bring you those controls *directly* under the main Form. If you have any subcontrols, like a Groupbox, they will be under that groupbox's `.Controls`. 
I see some SO posts that seem to suggest using recursion to get all subcontrols: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-winform-of-a-specific-type-button-textbox

Comment: Haha yeah @AvnerShahar-Kashtan, was just about to come here and say I found the issue - they are wrapped in group boxes. Rookie mistake! You can answer that if you like, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My WinForm experience is  a bit rusty, but if I remember correctly, `this.Controls` will only bring you those controls directly under the main Form. If you have any subcontrols, like a Groupbox, they will be under that groupbox's .`Controls`.

You can either explicitly iterate your Groupbox's controls, or you can use recursion to go over all child controls of the form, like you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-winform-of-a-specific-type-button-textbox).

Comment: `            foreach (GroupBox OptGroup in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
            {
                foreach (ComboBox DropDown in OptGroup.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
                    DropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect the control and its type for ComboBox...
This means you have to deal with nested loop to detect the controls

```
foreach (Control MyCtrl in this.Controls)
{
    DoAllRichTextBoxes(MyCtrl);
}

void DoAllRichTextBoxes(Control control)
{
    ComboBox Cmb = control as ComboBox;
    TextBox TxtBx = control as TextBox;
    if (Cmb == null && TxtBx == null)
    {
        // deal with nested controls
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls) DoAllRichTextBoxes(c);
    }
    if (Cmb != null)
    {
        Cmb.GotFocus += new EventHandler(this.Tb_GotFocus);
        Cmb.LostFocus += new EventHandler(this.Tb_LostFocus);
        Cmb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.VehComn_KeyDown);
        Cmb.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(this.AllCombos_SelectedValueChanged);
    }
    if (TxtBx != null)
    {
        TxtBx.GotFocus += new EventHandler(this.Tb_GotFocus);
        TxtBx.LostFocus += new EventHandler(this.Tb_LostFocus);
        TxtBx.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.TbCmb_KeyPress);
        TxtBx.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.VehComn_KeyDown);
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiles but not working unfortunately, all combo-boxes still appear blank :(