# Find Windows Forms control by name using a pattern

Tags: .net, winforms, linq

I want to list all controls inside another control which have names starting with "btnOverlay". I can't use `Controls.Find`, because it needs an exact match. I believe I can use LINQ for this, but I'm not very experienced on that. Is it possible? How can I do it?

I'm using .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could search for them with LINQ via:

```
var matches = control.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                     .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("btnOverlay"));
```

The `Cast<T>` call is required, as `ControlCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only `IEnumerable`.  Also, this doesn't do a recursive search, but only searches the contained controls directly.  If recursion is required, you'll likely need to refactor this into a [method similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-winform-of-a-specific-type-button-textbox/3426721#3426721).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative without using LINQ:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.Name.StartsWith("btnOverlay"))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Feel free to rename `this.` with the control you want to use.