# Combine a number of groupboxes into a single searchable variable

Tags: c#

I'm making a Windows Form Application with C#.

One of my forms contains 5 group boxes, each containing 6 checkboxes inside.
I need to count all the checked checkboxes.

At the moment I have coded it as follows:

`int NumOfRacks1 = groupBoxPace.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                            .Count(cb => cb.Checked);`

However I would have to repeat the above 5 times and then add all the variables together to get an answer. I'm sure there is a smarter way to do this which cuts down the code.

I tried to combine three of them as follows:

`var allRacks = groupBoxSamsung.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Concat(groupBoxPace.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Concat(groupBox780.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()));`

But this didn't work as expected.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: *But this didn't work as expected.*  What did happen?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I just tried it again and it worked.
I'm not sure what I did the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to count all the checked checkboxes.

Is not working because you're not counting. Try this.

```
var items = (groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Concat(groupBox2.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()))
    .Where(ch => ch.Checked == true).Count();
```

There you have your count.

Comment: Thanks Randolf. My code seems to work now anyway, but I may switch to yours as it seems to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found a question on StackOverflow [**How to get all childControls of a type on a form**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-winform-of-a-specific-type-button-textbox) and extended it to **count the checked elements**.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = (from c in GetAll(this, typeof(CheckBox))
                    where (c as CheckBox).Checked
                    select c).Count().ToString();                    
}
// credits go to @PsychoCoder for this part
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type))
                                .Concat(controls)
                                .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

In general I think this snippet should do the trick and you *don't have to concat all groupBoxes*!

**EDIT**

Adapted to **count all checked checkBoxes** on your form, no matter if checkboxes are childControls or not.

```
Type type = typeof(CheckBox);
var controls = this.Controls.Cast<Control>();
label1.Text = controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl))
                            .Concat(controls)
                            .Where(c => c.GetType() == type && (c as CheckBox).Checked)
                            .Count().ToString();
```