# Disable Control From Other Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form 1 that opens Form2. How I make all textBox readonly in Form2 opens?

Form 1:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ReadOnly();
f2.ShowDialog();
```

Form 2:

```
public void ReadOnyTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            ((TextBox)(c)).ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}

public void ReadOnly()
{
     ReadOnyTextBoxes(groupBox1);
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Your code seems to work OK.

Comment: The textBoxes in Form2 are still not ReadOnly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with your idea, in order to make it work on all `TextBox`es you could do this with a recursive function, something like:

```
public void MakeReadOnlyTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            ((TextBox)(c)).ReadOnly = true;
        }
        else if(c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            MakeReadOnlyTextBoxes(c);
        }
    }
}

public void ReadOnly()
{
     ReadOnyTextBoxes(this);
}
```

Edited: you should use the `c` variable at the recursive call

Answer (score 2):

there could be other groupboxes or some containers in groupbox1. you need recursion.
[How to disable all controls on the form except for a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446129/how-to-disable-all-controls-on-the-form-except-for-a-button)