# foreach c# gives unable to cast error

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

I have a program written in C# with a clear button, which needs to clear the content of the entire form. For the button I used on foreach for the radiobuttons and one for the checkboxes.

```
foreach (RadioButton rad in quiztabs.TabPages)
{
    rad.Checked = false;
}
foreach (CheckBox chk in quiztabs.TabPages)
{
    chk.Checked = false;
}
```

However, when I click the clear button I get an `Unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Forms.TabPage to type System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton`.

Comment: Well, a TabPage is not a RadioButton, so...

Comment: but isn't that just the location? I mean how do I adress it then?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You misunderstand the behaviour of `foreach`: It won't *filter* all elements in `TabPages`, it will try to *cast all of them*.

If you want to *filter*, you can do so explicitly using LINQ:

```
    foreach (RadioButton rad in quiztabs.TabPages.OfType<RadioButton>())
    {
        rad.Checked = false;
    }
    foreach (CheckBox chk in quiztabs.TabPages.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        chk.Checked = false;
    }
```

However, this still won't solve your problem, since the [TabPages collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages.aspx) only contains `TabPage` elements. What you *probably* want is something like this:

```
foreach (TabPage page in quiztabs.TabPages) 
{
    foreach (RadioButton rad in page.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
    {
        rad.Checked = false;
    }
    foreach (CheckBox chk in page.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        chk.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad question, you simply did not understand and came to the right place to learn. +1 BTW @Heinzi, clearest explanation on the question.

Comment: I would accept this answer as the edit is exactly what you want (the original code example wouldnt find any radio buttons :P)

Comment: +1 for nice and clear answer. @Oliver, If you want to clear out all controls of a particular type from the form then [you may get them recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/961113) and then iterate through them using foreach.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `OfType<T>()` method:

```
foreach (RadioButton item in yourChildern.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

`quiztabs.TabPages.OfType<RadioButton>()` and `quiztabs.TabPages.OfType<CheckBox>()` instead of `quiztabs.TabPages` in your code.

Alternativly;

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is RadioButton)
   {
     c.Checked = false;
   }
}

foreach(Control i in this.Controls)
{
   if(i is CheckBox)
   {
     i.Checked = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `.TabPages` is a list of Tab Pages... I believe you want the controls on each tab page

```
foreach(TabPage t in quizTabs.TabPages)
{
       foreach (RadioButton rad in t.Controls)
        {
            rad.Checked = false;
        }
        foreach (CheckBox chk in t.Controls)
        {
            chk.Checked = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Note: you may wish to compare this with other answers about the OfType method (which i didnt know about)

Comment: You would stil have that same cast error: `foreach RadioButton rad in t.Controls` doesn't filter, it casts everything (and fails)

Comment: Hence the note.. I maintain my comment in this answer still explains why OPs code isnt working

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` needs to have an iterator (`rad` here) of the same type of whatever you want to iterate through (`TabPages` here):

So it would look something like:

```
foreach (TabPage tab in quiztabs.TabPages) {
```

Although `TabPages` would be whatever type of object that `quiztabs.TabPages` is.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

because, tabs in not a `radioButton`, you should do this instead,

```
foreach(TabPage tp in quizTabs.TabPages)
     {
        foreach (RadioButton rad in tp.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
        {
            rad.Checked = false;
        }
        foreach (CheckBox chk in tp.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            chk.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will inevitably throw (unless the ```tp.Controls``` is empty) because no control is both a RadioButton and a CheckBox.

Comment: @erikkallen there you go, :D I'm just sleepy :D

Answer (score 0):

**Take one** `List<>` **of type RadioButton and  all radiobutton in that list .**

```
List<RadioButton> list = new List<RadioButton>();
            list.Add(radioButton1);
            list.Add(radioButton2);
            list.Add(radioButton3);
            foreach (RadioButton item in list)
            {
                if(tabControl1.SelectedTab==tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex])
                item.Checked = false;
            }
```