# Store textbox values in an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a form with 10 TextBoxes and OK button.
When the OK button was clicked. I need to store the values from the textboxes to a string of array.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Did you try anything? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Can you show some code? Do you know how to read data from a text box and do you know how to store data in an array?

Comment: string[] list = new list[9]; list[0] = textbox1.Text;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to store the values from the textboxes to a string of array.

```
string[] array = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                              .Select(r=> r.Text)
                              .ToArray();
```

The above expects the TextBoxes to be on the `Form` directly, not inside a container, if they are inside multiple containers then you should [get all the controls recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button).

Make sure you include `using System.Linq;`.

If you are using lower frameworks than .Net Framework 3.5. Then you can use a simple foreach loop like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
  if(c is TextBox)
     list.Add((c as TextBox).Text);
}
```

*(this would work with .Net framework 2.0 onward)*

Comment: Smart! my alternative solution is to manually create the textboxes in code, instead of using the designer, and then the rest is trivial.

Comment: Habib, I am having this error 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType'

Comment: @QKWS, make sure you include `using System.Linq;` at the top.

Comment: @Habib May I know the assembly reference for System.Linq? I am having this error:The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @QKWS, what is the .Net framework you are using, it is supported from .Net 3.5 onward.

Comment: @QKWS, just updated the answer which is support in lower version of .Net framework as well.

Comment: Error: The type or namespace name 'Textbox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `Error: The type or namespace name 'Textbox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` OMG. and I provided a recursive lambda solution. @QKWS replace `Textbox` with `TextBox`

Answer (score 2):

To get all textboxes not only the direct childs of the form (*this*)

```
Func<Control, IEnumerable<Control>> allControls = null;
allControls = c => new Control[] { c }.Concat(c.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(x => allControls(x)));

var all = allControls(this).OfType<TextBox>()
            .Select(t => t.Text)
            .ToList();
```