# Generic All Controls Method

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, generics

Couldn't think of a better title so appologies..

I'm trying to convert [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/1324033), which will retrieve all child controls of a form, to be an extension method as well as accept interfaces as inputs. So far I am up to

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll<T>(this Control control) where T : class
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll<T>(ctrl))
                                .Concat(controls)
                                .Where(c => c is T);
}
```

which works fine except I need to add `OfType<T>()` when calling it to get access to its properties.

e.g (this == form)

```
this.GetAll<IMyInterface>().OfType<IMyInterface>()
```

I'm struggling to make the return type into a generic return type `IEnumerable<T>`, so that I don't have to include a `OfType` which will just return the same result but cast correctly.

Anyone have any suggestions?

(Changing return type to `IEnumerable<T>` causes the `Concat` to throw

> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<T>`' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery`<System.Windows.Forms.Control>`'

Comment: Replace 'public IEnumerable<Control>' with 'public IEnumerable<T>'?

Comment: Causes the error at the bottom to be thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Concat` would want an `IEnumerable<T>` as well - not an `IEnumerable<Control>`. This should work though:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(this Control control) where T : class
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll<T>(ctrl))
                                .Concat(controls.OfType<T>()));
}
```

Comment: @Servy: I don't think so - `controls` is still *all* the child controls when we recurse. `OfType` is only applied to the *direct* children.

Comment: Yeah, in this case it recurses first so it would be fine, most implementations don't.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for the reply, This causes the same problem as last sentence in my question (can't convert from Control to T for Concat)

Comment: I would only add 'where T : Control' instead of 'where T : class', since the method is only applicable to Control-derived classes anyway.

Comment: Nevermind, the error seemed to remove itself when I rebuilt, thanks!. @RogerN, my interfaces don't derive from control

Comment: @Sayse: An earlier version of the answer *did* have the problem, but then I moved a couple of brackets :)

Comment: @RogerN: I originally did that - then I spotted that in the question, the sample was an interface... and the method *is* applicable to interfaces that some controls may implement.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I had noticed but didn't realise there were more changes made; you missed one at the end :) Thanks again