# Get all Checkboxes in Winform / UserControl by reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, user-controls

I would like to add a dynamic `CheckAll()` method to check all checkboxes declared in my class.

I tried following code:

```
class MyContol : UserControl
{
  ///
  ///  HIDDEN but there is plenty of checkboxes declaration
  ///

  private void CheckAll()
  {
    FieldInfo[] props = this.GetType().GetFields();

    foreach (FieldInfo p in props)
    {
      if (p.FieldType is CheckBox)
      {
         /// TODO: Check my box
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... but `props` is empty. I have no idea how to target checkboxes made with designer part.

Do you know using `Reflection` how to target added by design view components?

Comment: I use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454389/generic-all-controls-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkboxes of the control should all be child controls. That is, they are children (or possibly children of children) in the `Control.Controls` collection. Furthermore, controls *do not have to have a reference to them as a property or field of the class*. For example, I can add a checkbox to an existing control with `myControl.Controls.Add(new CheckBox())`. Therefore you do not need reflection here, nor will it really get you what you want - if I'm understanding you correctly.

Try enumerating them this way (to check for example controls in a panel you will need to do the recursive search):

```
private void CheckAll(Control parent)
{
    foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c is CheckBox)
            Check((CheckBox)c);

        CheckAll(c);
    }
}

private void CheckAll()
{
    CheckAll(this);
}
```

Comment: replacing `CheckAll(c.Controls);` by `CheckAll(c);` works fine

Answer (score 1):

By default controls on your UserControl are private fields so I guess you should provide NonPublic flag as the parameter for binding attributes in GetFields method try this:

```
this.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

but you don't need reflection to achieve what you're looking for here.

Comment: I see but finally I prefer solution introduced by *lc.* which is as you said without `Reflection`