# How to create RowHeadersVisible changed event for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridrowheader

I have a Windows Form, DataGridView and two buttons.
When I will press the button1 it changes a value of RowHeadersVisible to true.
When I will press the button2 it changes a value of RowHeadersVisible to false.

```
    public Form1()             
    {             
        InitializeComponent();         


        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    }  

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = true;
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    }
```

I cannot find any kind of events about "RowHeadersVisible" value changing in "DataGridView" class. As I mentioned "CellFormatting" event works for this action but it appears often, almost for all kind of action made in datagridview1.
I think we might create a custom event handler in order to make different decisions.
When "RowHeadersVisible" changes the value to false I need to call another function inside "CustomEvent".

```
    private void CustomEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SomeFunction();
    }
```

On the other hand "DataGridTableStyle" class has the event "RowHeadersVisibleChanged".
So How to solve this problem?

Comment: use [Anchor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: [Generic All Controls Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454389/generic-all-controls-method)

Comment: it is not about scaling control....

Comment: WinForms is really bad at scaling Controls. Is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2007/10/05/ui-scaling-ui-zooming-with-wpf.aspx) the effect you're after?

Comment: please forget about scaling controls....

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.5, you should get help.
Dissolve it in the following way.

Represents the table drawn by the *System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid* control at run time.

```
// Instantiate the EventHandler. 
public void AttachRowHeaderVisibleChanged()
{
   myDataGridTableStyle.RowHeadersVisibleChanged += new EventHandler (MyDelegateRowHeadersVisibleChanged);
}

// raise the event when RowHeadersVisible property is changed. 
private void MyDelegateRowHeadersVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string myString = "'RowHeadersVisibleChanged' event raised, Row Headers are";
   if (myDataGridTableStyle.RowHeadersVisible)
      myString += " visible";
   else
      myString += " not visible";

   MessageBox.Show(myString, "RowHeader information");
}

// raise the event when a button is clicked. 
private void myButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (myDataGridTableStyle.RowHeadersVisible)
      myDataGridTableStyle.RowHeadersVisible = false;
   else
      myDataGridTableStyle.RowHeadersVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: You are talking about "myDataGridTableStyle" but not about "DataGridView"!!

Comment: myDataGridTableStyle is System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid component in .net 4.5