# how to change size of controls in different panels or forms (winform) c#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

There is some checkboxes in my forms and some of them in panels in a specific form(two different matter).
I placed a button that when user click on that, the size of all checkboxes should change(in all panels and forms).

And another question is that,how can I found that what is the type of controls in my app Programmatically?

Thanks for your help.
I placed a button and added a event handler.
and for founding the the type of control,I used the name of control
Here is my try:

```
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
                if (ctrl.Name.Contains("combo"))  
                    checkbox1.SetSize = new Size(40,40);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your code.

Comment: What is the problem you are currently having with the first question? Your second question depends on your required usage.

Comment: @Sayse I want just to know the type of the control.

Comment: To do what with it though? You can use `GetType()` but then what are you doing with it because there are other things you could use ... `is`, `as`, `OfType<T>()`, generics......

Comment: thank you. You're right,that's the answer that I forgot. but what is the answer of my question?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use one Function to handle multiple OnClick - events, you can get the origin out of the sender (the sender is a given parameter for the handler implementation)

(If this was the question, you should clearify what exactly you want to do and show your relevant code)

Answer (score 0):

**Change according to comment:**

You can loop through all controls to find all checkboxes:

```
    private void ProcessControls(Control containerControl)
    {
        foreach (Control control in containerControl.Controls)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
            {
                ChangeCheckBoxProperties((CheckBox)control);
            }
            else
            {
                ProcessControls(control);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ChangeCheckBoxProperties(CheckBox cb)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

You can call this method for your main form.

On mind, you should think about your aproach in general, because if you use such loops, it seems that something is not right in your solution.

Comment: thank you. You're right,that's the answer that I forgot. but what is the answer of my question?

Comment: @user3787313 I have updated the answer, so please check.

Comment: Just be careful looping through all controls on form, because it can bring some performance issues (depends on number of controls).

Comment: I have checkboxes in some panels but size of them won't change. that's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use [this extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17454513/1324033) to loop over all checkboxes

```
foreach(var checkBox in this.GetAll<CheckBox>())
    checkBox.Size = new Size(40,40);
```

Without this you would have to loop over the panels seperately

```
foreach(var panel in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    foreach(var checkbox in panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        //set size in panel

foreach(var checkbox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    //set size in form
```

Comment: the extension method should define in static class,then how can I use it in winform?

Comment: @user3787313 - [Extension Methods msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx)