# How do I change the color of a collection of button controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 30 buttons on my form, and I want to add them to a list and then change the forecolor of them all using `foreach`

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button> { button3, button4, button5......etc };
foreach (Button btn in buttons)
{
    btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

However the color of the buttons never actually changes.

Comment: Please be more specific about the "does not work" part: does it "crash", "does not compile", or "has no visible effect"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic All Controls Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454389/generic-all-controls-method)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Nothing happens, i thought the code is incomplete or incorrect

Comment: Is the code even reached? Do you run it with the debugger and step through the code?

Comment: but where did you put this code? what is this, winform?

Comment: It could be [Winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx) or [Webforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.forecolor.aspx)

Comment: It is Winforms, i put this code under a button click event

Comment: So you put the code under an event, but did you ever verify that the code is *actually reached*? Do you know how to use the debugger, or add console or trace output statements?

Comment: Are you sure that your list contains actual buttons that are placed on your form?

Comment: Make sure the FlatStyle property of the buttons are set to Standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is on the ForeColor property. I would use the BackColor/Background property to change the color.

If you are using WinForms :

```
button.BackColor = Color.White;
```

If you are using WPF :

```
button.Background = Brushes.White;
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you described the difference between ForeColor and BackColor instead of just saying to use the other one.

Comment: It seems like you were right, what i actually wanted was to change the BackColor, now i know the difference between them two

Comment: @mason well I don't really know what changing the ForeColor property does but I know what the BackColor does.

Comment: I have little experience with WinForms, but typically ForeColor is the color of the text, and BackColor is the color of the rest of the button (the space around the text within the borders of the button).

Comment: ForeColor applies to the content of a control. So for instance the text color