# How to use Recursive Method in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

i need to find controls in my forms. in asp.net i used Recursive method to do it.now how to do in winforms

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id)
        return root;

    return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
       .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
       .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
}
```

any idea..thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **root.Name** in place of **root.ID** in win forms.

Comment: what to pass in root parameter.if i pass forms its showing error

Comment: You can pass the form object like this:Form1 f=new Form1();
Control ctl=FindControlRecursive(f, "textBox1");

Answer (score 2):

Each control has a [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which in fact is a [ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This collection itself has a method [Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes 2 parameters. The first parameter is the name of the control which you want to find, the second parameter indicates wether to include all children into the search.

As a sample:

```
Control[] allButton1 = this.Controls.Find("button1", true);
// for your example
Control[] foundControls = this.Controls.Find(root.Name,true);
```