# How can I dispose of dynamically created controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, dispose

I am dynamically creating controls on top of TabPages that are, of course, on a TabControl. I want to be able to dynamically dispose of these, too. How can I do that? Calling Clear on the TabControl's TabPages collection actually disposes the TabPages themselves, which defeats the purpose of "starting over" with new dynamically created controls on those pages.

Calling tabPageBla.Controls.Clear() is close to what I want, but it also disposes a container control that I have on each TabPage (FlowControlLayout) that I need to keep.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this (dispose only the dynamically-created controls, but not any of the others)?

### UPDATE

Will this work - will grandchildren of TabControl1 also be found (children of the tab pages)?:

```
List<Control> ctrls = new List<Control>();
ctrls.AddRange(tabControl1.Controls);
foreach (var ctrl in ctrls)
{
    // Controls named "panelRowBla", "richTextBoxBla", and "pictureBoxBla" need to be retained
    string ctrlName = ctrl.Name;
    if ((ctrlName.Contains("panelRow")) ||
        (ctrlName.Contains("richTextBox")) ||
        (ctrlName.Contains("pictureBox")))
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

That's odd; I could have sworn this was just compiling, but now I'm getting "*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'*"

(on the "AddRange()" line).

Comment: Sorry - added the "Winforms" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell if the control was created in the designer or dynamically. But what you can do, is to create a list of all the controls, which exist at the very start (controls which were created in the designer).

**Create a new list to the class' root, to hold all the "original" controls:**

```
List<Control> DesignerControls;
```

**Use this modified PsychoCoder's method (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/2538037) to list all controls (including controls inside controls):**

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control)
{
   var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

   return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl))
                  .Concat(controls);
}
```

**Before you have added any controls dynamically, run this line (for example in the constructor):**

```
DesignerControls = GetAll(this).ToList();
```

**Then add this static method for disposing the dynamically created controls:**

```
public static bool DisposeDynamicObjects(List<Control> NonDynamicControls, List<Control> ControlsToDispose)
{
   try
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < ControlsToDispose.Count; i++)
      {
         if (ControlsToDispose[i] != null &&
             !ControlsToDispose[i].IsDisposed &&
             !NonDynamicControls.Contains(ControlsToDispose[i]))
         {
            ControlsToDispose[i].Dispose();
            --i;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); return false; }
}
```

**When you want to dispose dynamically created controls, use this:**

```
DisposeDynamicObjects(DesignerControls, GetAll(tabControl1).ToList());
```

The code above disposes all dynamically created controls inside `tabControl1.Controls`. You can replace the `tabControl1` with other controls, like `this` for example, so all dynamically created controls are deleted from the whole form.

Comment: Thanks; I changed "tabPage1" to "tabControl1" (hoping that was what you meant - but that seems to dispose of the controls without removing them from sight - do I need to call Refresh or some such for that?

Comment: I updated the answer with some new code. Thats a one way to use it.

Comment: In the foreach loop calling DisposeDynamicObjects(), I get, "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.Control>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'"

Comment: I updated the `DisposeDynamicObjects()`-method's parameter types. Please copy and use this new version. Also notice the `.Cast<Control>().ToList()`.

Comment: The last two foreaches above are exactly what I'm using (except that I don't have "Form1" prepended to the call to DisposeDynamicObjects()), and I still get that err msg.

Comment: Oh, my bad - I see the main method itself changed; compiles now...still doesn't get rid of the dynamic controls, though (which are on FlowLayoutPanels and are images inside PictureBoxes).

Comment: You can use recursive method to list All controls inside controls, including GroupBoxes and their controls. Here is one link: http://kon-phum.com/tutors/pascal/programming_cs_getcontrolsonform.html . You could use it like this: `DesignerControls = GetAllControls(tabControl1.Controls);`. And when you wan't to dispose the objects run `Form1.DisposeDynamicObjects(DesignerControls, GetAllControls(tabControl1.Controls));`. I haven't tested out that link's method, but it should work.

Comment: No, the method from that link doesn't compile, either; it says, "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: I rewrote the answer to make it more versatile. I also tested it quickly, and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the control from the parent, you can explicitly `Dispose` it, ie:

```
 parent.Controls.Remove(theControl);
 ((IDisposable)theControl).Dispose();
```

Given your edits, you should be able to do:

```
var toRemove = tabControls1
      .Controls
      .Cast<Control>()
      .Where(c => !(c.Name.Contains("panelRow") || c.Name.Contains("richTextBox") || c.Name.Contains("pictureBox")))
      .ToList();

foreach(var c in toRemove)
{
     tabControls1.Controls.Remove(c);
     ((IDisposable)c).Dispose();
}
```

This will remove all of the controls from the `tabControl1` which don't match your filter.

Comment: I need a way to loop through them, though, because there are potentially a googleplex of them.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Just keep a local copy of the controls in `parent.Controls` (ie: `var toRemove = parent.Controls.ToList();`) and remove each.

Comment: As a funny side note; with todays current system, you will get an `OutOfMemoryException` trying to instantiate a *googleplex* of controls :P

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Quite possibly; on a personal level, I get an OOME trying to remember what I had for lunch yesterday.

Comment: By using `Dispose()` the `Control` is removed from the Control.ControlCollection of its current parent control.

Comment: @AshtonWoods True, but I find that I like explicitly removing anyways - it makes the intent more clear