# Assign checkboxes to an checkbox-array using a for loop in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, checkbox

I'd like to do this:

```
CheckBox[] boxarray = new CheckBox[4];
    boxarray[0] = checkBox1;
    boxarray[1] = checkBox2;
    boxarray[2] = checkBox3;
    boxarray[3] = checkBox4;
```

using a for loop - because I have about 600 checkboxes. I thought about this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<= 600; i++)
    {
    boxes[i] = checkBox[i] ;
    }
```

But whatever I tried - it didn't work. I hope you know what I mean.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you creating these CheckBoxes in Visual Studio designer?

Comment: *because I have about 600 checkboxes* I'd love to see how the UI looks.

Comment: do you mean you have ~600 entries to be placed in a single checkbox? or you actually want to create **600** checkboxes? Seems pretty extreme to me!!!

Comment: is this a web forms application? winforms? wpf?

Comment: What is `boxes[]`?  What is `checkBox[]`?

Comment: please make your question more clear?..its not exact from your question

Comment: Okay. Yes, it seems weird but I really have 600 checkboxes. By the way: I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop and it is a Windows Form Application. I would like to connect the checkboxes to a mysql database and thought it would be easier if I was creating a checkbox-array. Please don't ask for details. As you may see, I am no expert but I think this array could it make easier. Not to have to assign one checkbox to an array's item each, I thought about the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have these CheckBoxes on your form, then you can add them to an array (or List, which would be much easier to do) like that:

```C#
List<CheckBox> checkBoxesList = new List<CheckBox>();
foreach (Control ctrl in FormName.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
    {
        checkBoxesList.Add(ctrl as CheckBox);
    }
}
```

Remember, simply writing:
`checkBox1`, `checkBox2`
won't make it possible to get them like `checkBox[0]` - it's not an array, it's just a name with '1' or '2' in the end.

Answer (score 0):

you are not able to specifiy the name of the checkboxes in the code like you have done, because `i` wont get changed.

you have to create new instances of CheckBox like:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<= 600; i++)
{
    //This will create a new instance of a CheckBox
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox()

    //At this point the checkbox is empty and not visible anywhere
    //So you have to change some properties:
    cb.Text = "Check me!";
    cb.Top = Ycoord; //you should change this depending on i like +(i*30)
    cb.Left = Xcoord;
    cb.name = "checkbox" + i.toString();
    //To recognize if one of your Checkboxes is checked/unchecked you need to add
    //an event like this (for the event see down below)
    cb.CheckedChanged += checkedChangedEvent;
    //then you need to add the checkbox to your Array
    boxes[i] = cb;
    //to make those checkboxes visible you need to add them to your form
    //or Panel:
    myForm.Controls.Add(cb);
}
```

The Event:

```
public void checkedChangedEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((CheckBox)sender).name + " is now Checked == " + ((CheckBox)sender).Checked.toString();
}
```

you have to specify which Checkbox was Checked/Unchecked by its name, because every CheckBox is firing the same event.

EDIT2:

to get the number of the checkbox you can do something like this in the event:

```
int cbNumber = 0;
try
{
    cbNumber = System.Convert.toInt32(((CheckBox)sender).name.Replace("checkbox",""));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: I read about that, too. But actually I've never done that before so I'm not even sure about what this will look like. Maybe you could explain what it does, please?

Comment: Added more details ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the current setup, you'll have to use FindControl (assuming ASP.net, winforms and WPF work differently):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 600; i++)
{
    boxes[i] = Page.FindControl("checkbox" + i);
}
```

---

Update for windows forms: There is actually a method you can use to find all controls of a specific type:

[How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

> Here's another option for you. I tested it by creating a sample
>   application, I then put a GroupBox and a GroupBox inside the initial
>   GroupBox. Inside the nested GroupBox I put 3 TextBox controls and a
>   button. This is the code I used (even includes the recursion you were
>   looking for)
>
> ```
> public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control,Type type) {
>     var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
>     return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl,type))
>                    .Concat(controls)
>                    .Where(c => c.GetType() == type); 
> }
> ```
>
> To test it in the form load event I wanted a count of all controls inside
>   the initial GroupBox
>
> ```
> private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>     var c = GetAll(this,typeof(TextBox));
>     MessageBox.Show("Total Controls: " + c.Count());
> }
> ```
>
> And it returned the proper count each time, so I think this will work perfectly for
>   what you're looking for :)

If you have other checkboxes on your form that you don't want to add, you'll have to use the following method:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 600; i++)
{
    boxes[i] = this.Controls.Find("checkbox" + i, true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;
}
```

Comment: I don't, actually. I just assumed it. I have no logical reason to assume that it's ASP.NET aside from it being the technology I know how to explain it in best. The concept remains the same though: he'll have to concatenate his counter to the part that always stays the same and look them up manually.

Comment: Updated with Winform methodology since that's what the OP uses.