# How to create a list of panels already existing in WinForm Application (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list

Context: 
I am creating mock-ups for a web based application. I use WinForms Application to do this. In the future I will use WebForms but this question applies to both I'm sure.

Question: 
I have panels that are transparent which I place over a webpage-sized picturebox. The panels act as clickable "links" to "navigate" to "pages".

In actuality when a panel is clicked the picturebox (which serves as the background) changes to a screen capture of a different webpage giving the appearance of web navigation. The panels act as masks on things users click on to navigate.

I would like to add these existing panels into a list for the purpose of changing them.
For example, I would like to change their .Enabled attribute set to false; in one statement.

I currently accomplish this by doing this:

```
    public void TurnOffPanels()
    {
        aPnl.Enabled = false;
        bPnl.Enabled = false;
        cPnl.Enabled = false;
        dPnl.Enabled = false;
        ePnl.Enabled = false;
        fPnl.Enabled = false;
    {
```

My question is: how can code this using a list of my panels?

PS: This is my first question here so please feel free to berate me for format, noobness...whateves

Comment: use a loop to iterate it?  Is that all you need?  `foreach(var item in myList) item.Enabled = false`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oof, well, I wouldn't use winforms applications for mockups. There's plenty of cheap mockup applications like balsamiq and the like to do that, or gimp if you want to provide a visual aid.

However, I think you're meaning to say that you're developing "prototypes" in winforms. Prototypes allow people to interact while mockups are just flat images.

Anyway, if you want to hide a list of panels, you can just create a field in your codebehind of the panels you want to flicker, and just operate on that.

iE:

```
public class Form {
    List<Panel> myPanels = new List<Panel>();
    public Form() {
          myPanels.Add(aPnl);
          myPanels.Add(bPnl);
          //etc
    }
    public TurnOffPanels(){
        foreach(var panel in myPanels){
             panel.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Also your question is formatted fine, and you gave plenty of detail. As far as first questions go, good job!

Answer (score 0):

If the panel are Childrens of the same form, then:

```
foreach(Panel p in this.Controls)
     p.Enabled = false;
```