# C# - Use too many buttons as 1 variable

Tags: c#

I have a fairly simple question. I want to change the background color of 15 buttons, 
but is is very cumbersome to write

```
button1.backgroundColor = Color.black
button2.backgroundColor = Color.black
.
.
.
```

How i can assign the color to all these buttons at once?

Like:

```
something allButtons = { button1.backgroundColor, button2.backgroundcolor .... }
```

I know how to do this in obj-c:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[tag:i];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor Color.black];
}
```

but how to accomplish this in C#?

Comment: Array. This comment's mostly filler.

Comment: What i do with array ? please explain more or answer with code

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: is it Winform or WPF?

Comment: Are you using win forms, web forms, ASP.MVC or WPF?

Comment: if using Winforms, why not go through all controls on the form where the type is a button? of course, of course this will change for ALL buttons on the form....

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to iterate through all the controls on the form, looking for buttons.

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            c.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think, `c is Button` is better condition.

Comment: @Vlad: and even better - `Controls.OfType<Button>()`. Of course, if OP uses WinForms.

Comment: Not if the buttons are inside some container and not in the main Form.Controls container. Looping in this way will change only the buttons that are in the root container. (IE. Try to place a button inside a GroupBox.

Comment: Yep, you would have to do a recursive loop if you've got containers. Here's an even better implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button

Answer (score 1):

You put your buttons in an button array

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[] {button1, button2, .....};
```

Or in a `List<Button>`

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>() { button1, button2, ....);
```

Next you loop over the button array or the List in the same way

```
foreach(Button btn in buttons)
    btn.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

Another way to change this property is looping using the Forms.Controls container. But this will work only if the buttons are all contained in the Form.Controls collection.

```
foreach (Control btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    btn.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

To fix the problem of buttons contained in inner ControlCollection you should use a recursive function that loops on every control container and reach buttons eventually inside that container

```
public void SetBackground(Control.ControlCollection coll)
{
    foreach(Control ctr in coll)
    {
       if(ctr.Controls.Count > 0)
          SetBackground(ctr.Controls);
       else
       {
          Button btn = ctr as Button;
          if(btn != null) btn.BackColor = Color.Black;
       }
    }
}
```

and call it from the toplevel collection

```
SetBackground(this.Controls);
```

It is a lot more complicated, so I prefer to use an array to explicitily declare the buttons that need to be changed.

Comment: This assumes, that someone must create this array. While this is obvious and universal solution, it is rather ugly, because, depending on UI framework, controls are contained already somewhere. OP just need to determine the scope, in which buttons should be affected.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but creating the array will give a better control on which buttons should be changed in the loop. And we are talking about WinForms.

Comment: Better use a List<Button> or List<Control> so you can add or remove dynamically..

Comment: @TaW yes this would be better, but probably in this context the list is of no practical advantage because I suppose that the buttons are all know before