# Find a label in WinForms which contains certain text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In C# Windows form application, how to find the label on the form which contains the text I'm looking for?

For example: I am trying to search a label whose `Text` property contains "25".

Comment: Any attempt / effort on your side? Is it .NET 2 or 4? And what has the code provider to do with it?

Answer (score 8):

You can find it using linq this way:

```
var control =  this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x => x is Label && x.Text.Contains("25"));
```

or as @Sayse suggested just filter on `Label` type:

```
var Labelcontrol =  this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x => x.Text.Contains("25"));
```

### Explanation:

If we want to fetch all controls of the form we have to do :

```
var AllControls = this.Controls.OfType<Control>();
```

and if we want to fetch only Controls of Type `Label` then:

```
var LabelControls = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();
```

Here `this` refers to current form of application.

### UPDATE:

If you have label in nested controls, means inside some user control or some other control, then you need to check recrursively as in [this SO post (How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to just get controls of type `Label`?

Comment: you are right @Sayse , updated post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all controls are of type `Control` too :) (It returns a `ControlCollection` and it looks like you can only [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Control`s to it

Comment: yes @Sayse obviously

Comment: I mean the first `OfType` would just return the original query - +1 for the effort anywho

Comment: agreed @Sayse i posted that code first so i updated the post and did'nt removed it.:)

Comment: This solution is fine as long as there are no nested controls in the `Form`. But the OP didn't say that was a valid assumption.