# What causes this inconsistent enumeration? Accessing Controls of an UltraGroupBox using LINQ vs. foreach in a Load handler

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, infragistics

When using the `GetAll` method in the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button) to recursively get all ComboBoxes on a Form, the results behave strangely if the ComboBoxes are in an UltraGroupBox. I get inconsistent results when manipulating the returned IEnumerable with LINQ vs. foreach. See the standalone program example further down to reproduce the problem for yourself. The problem is exemplified in the following code snippet:

```
var combos = GetAll(this, typeof(ComboBox)).Cast<ComboBox>();

var linqNames = combos.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
var foreachNames = new List<string>();

foreach (var comboBox in combos)
{
    foreachNames.Add(comboBox.Name);
}

Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", linqNames));
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", foreachNames));
```

Output:

```
cbo1, cbo2, cbo3, cbo4, cbo5, cbo6, cbo7

cbo1, cbo3, cbo5, cbo1, cbo5, cbo5, cbo7
```

Notice that cbo2, cbo4, and cbo6 are missing from the foreach result. This is executing in the Form's load event handler. The ComboBoxes are all within the same Infragistics UltraGroupBox. What causes this odd behavior? Does the Controls property of an UltraGroupBox have side effects?

**Edit:** I realize that adding ToList() to the return of GetAll (as below) causes the results to match, but I want to know why the enumeration is inconsistent when just using the IEnumerable.

```
var combos = GetAll(this, typeof(ComboBox)).Cast<ComboBox>().ToList();
```

**Edit 2:** Here is the Designer code for the standalone program (using .NET 4.0 and Infragistics NetAdvantage 2013.1 assemblies):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Infragistics.Win.Appearance appearance1 = new Infragistics.Win.Appearance();
        this.grpTest = new Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraGroupBox();
        this.label20 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label18 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label14 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cbo4 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.cbo6 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.cbo5 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.cbo2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.cbo3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.cbo1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.grpTest)).BeginInit();
        this.grpTest.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // grpTest
        // 
        this.grpTest.BorderStyle = Infragistics.Win.Misc.GroupBoxBorderStyle.None;
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.label20);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.label18);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.label14);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.label5);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.cbo4);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.cbo6);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.cbo5);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.cbo2);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.cbo3);
        this.grpTest.Controls.Add(this.cbo1);
        this.grpTest.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
        appearance1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
        appearance1.BackColor2 = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
        appearance1.FontData.BoldAsString = "True";
        appearance1.FontData.SizeInPoints = 10F;
        appearance1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.grpTest.HeaderAppearance = appearance1;
        this.grpTest.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.grpTest.Name = "grpTest";
        this.grpTest.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(463, 261);
        this.grpTest.TabIndex = 13;
        this.grpTest.Text = "Test";
        // 
        // label20
        // 
        this.label20.AutoSize = true;
        this.label20.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(135, 180);
        this.label20.Name = "label20";
        this.label20.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 13);
        this.label20.TabIndex = 25;
        this.label20.Text = "Combo 6";
        // 
        // label18
        // 
        this.label18.AutoSize = true;
        this.label18.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 158);
        this.label18.Name = "label18";
        this.label18.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 13);
        this.label18.TabIndex = 24;
        this.label18.Text = "Combo 5";
        // 
        // label14
        // 
        this.label14.AutoSize = true;
        this.label14.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(133, 136);
        this.label14.Name = "label14";
        this.label14.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 13);
        this.label14.TabIndex = 23;
        this.label14.Text = "Combo 4";
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this.label5.AutoSize = true;
        this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 114);
        this.label5.Name = "label5";
        this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 13);
        this.label5.TabIndex = 22;
        this.label5.Text = "Combo 3";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this.label4.AutoSize = true;
        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 92);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 13);
        this.label4.TabIndex = 21;
        this.label4.Text = "Combo 2";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 70);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 13);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 20;
        this.label3.Text = "Combo 1";
        // 
        // cbo4
        // 
        this.cbo4.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
        this.cbo4.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cbo4.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "A",
        "B"});
        this.cbo4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, 133);
        this.cbo4.Name = "cbo4";
        this.cbo4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.cbo4.TabIndex = 7;
        // 
        // cbo6
        // 
        this.cbo6.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
        this.cbo6.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cbo6.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "A",
        "B"});
        this.cbo6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, 177);
        this.cbo6.Name = "cbo6";
        this.cbo6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.cbo6.TabIndex = 11;
        // 
        // cbo5
        // 
        this.cbo5.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
        this.cbo5.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cbo5.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"});
        this.cbo5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, 155);
        this.cbo5.Name = "cbo5";
        this.cbo5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.cbo5.TabIndex = 9;
        // 
        // cbo2
        // 
        this.cbo2.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
        this.cbo2.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cbo2.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"});
        this.cbo2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, 89);
        this.cbo2.Name = "cbo2";
        this.cbo2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.cbo2.TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // cbo3
        // 
        this.cbo3.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
        this.cbo3.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cbo3.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "A",
        "B"});
        this.cbo3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, 111);
        this.cbo3.Name = "cbo3";
        this.cbo3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.cbo3.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // cbo1
        // 
        this.cbo1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
        this.cbo1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cbo1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"});
        this.cbo1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, 67);
        this.cbo1.Name = "cbo1";
        this.cbo1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.cbo1.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(463, 277);
        this.Controls.Add(this.grpTest);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.grpTest)).EndInit();
        this.grpTest.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpTest.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraGroupBox grpTest;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cbo3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cbo2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cbo1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label20;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label18;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label14;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cbo6;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cbo5;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cbo4;
}
}
```

And the main implementation file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!DesignMode)
            {
                var combos = GetAll(this, typeof(ComboBox)).Cast<ComboBox>();
                var names = combos.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
                var foreachNames = new List<string>();

                foreach (var comboBox in combos)
                {
                    foreachNames.Add(comboBox.Name);
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", names));
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", foreachNames));
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
        {
            IEnumerable<Control> controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

            return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type))
                .Concat(controls)
                .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? That looks very odd to me.

Comment: I could could not reproduce this problem at my end. Tried changing TabIndex, Z-Order, Visible, Enabled properties. The order was same in both methods. Can you please explain the complete scenario?

Comment: *Very* doubtful that anybody could ever get a repro from this code snippet or that it matches the real code.  Google "Linq deferred execution" to learn more.

Comment: The problem appears to be caused by the Infragistics UltraGroupBox. I'll add the appropriate tag and post the standalone code.

Comment: Standalone code posted. This is definitely caused by UltraGroupBox. Maybe I can get some clarification from the Infragistics crowd.

Comment: Which version of infragistics controls are you using? could not reproduce with either 7.3 nor 13.1.

Comment: I'm using 13.1. The assemblies used: Infragistics4.Shared.v13.1.dll, Infragistics4.Win.Misc.v13.1.dll, Infragistics4.Win.v13.1.dll.

Comment: Can you tell me the service release version that you use in your project? Infragistics 13.1.2013.????

Comment: The version I'm using is 13.1.20131.1001