# Adding and removing groupboxes dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, groupbox

I have a form containing two buttons.

The first one adds some `GroupBoxes` to the form, with this handler:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GroupBox[] g_arr = new GroupBox[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < g_arr.Length; i++)
    {
        g_arr[i] = new GroupBox();
        g_arr[i].Location = new Point(280, (i*-50) + 300);
        g_arr[i].Size = new Size(337, 380);

        this.Controls.Add(g_arr[i]);
            }
        }
```

The second one is supposed to remove every `GroupBoxes` inside the form, **but not all of them disappear when it's clicked**:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is GroupBox)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(c);
        }                    
    }
}
```

Why doesn't my remove button manage to remove every `GroupBox`?

Comment: the iterating collection of `foreach` is read-only. It is surprising that an exception is not thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Don't modify the collection while you are iterating. You can use `OfType` method to get all `GroupBoxes` and `ToList` to copy them into a list so you can iterate over it instead of the original collection:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToList())
{
     this.Controls.Remove(c);
}
```

This will only remove the `GroupBox` controls that are direct child of the `Form`.If you have nested controls then you need a recursive search  like in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/3010968)

Comment: Thank you sir/mam. Actually I tried the `OfType` method first but I don't know about `ToList`:)