# Disable all texboxes, datetimepicker, comboboxes programatically

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, textbox

is there a way where I can disable all texboxes, datetimepicker, comboboxes in a form load?

I have a condition in my form_load like this:

```
    private void frmTWLeasing_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.Text = sTitle;
            this.txtNinja1.Text = sEnable;
            if (sEnable == "Disabled")
            {

                disable all textboxes, datetimepicker, comboboxes or gridviews
            }
            else
            {
               enable all textboxes, datetimepicker, comboboxes or gridviews
            }
        }
```

I have so many textboxes, datetimepicker, and comboboxes in this form including a datagridview, so is there any syntax where I can call all textboxes, datetimepicker, comboboxes so that I can disable this at one time? It's hard to disable it one by one.. Hope you can help me guys Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It would be easier to put the ones you want to disable into a Panel and then just disable that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then in `Where()` get specific type control and then iterate and disable them or enable them as desired like this:

```
 if (sEnable == "Disabled")
 {

    var controls = this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x=>x is TextBox || x is ComboBox || x is DateTimePicker);

    foreach(var control in controls)
          control.Enabled = false;
 }
```

You will need to add `using System.Linq` in your class

If you have controls in nested controls, means inside some user control or some other control, then you need to check recursively as in [this SO post (How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Comment: I've tried it, but i'm getting an error on OfType<Control>

Comment: Note that both cases are handled (enable and disable) if one simply uses `control.Enabled = sEnable != "Disabled"`. Also, the above will only handle the first level of controls. A recursive implementation should be used if any of the targeted controls are sub-children within the form.

Comment: There is a typo. Ehsan meant to write `this.Controls.OfType<Control>()`...note the parentheses.

Comment: @PeterDuniho totally agree, i have just gave idea to OP how to get started

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Right, I did add that, however it didn't work.. Nothing happened.

Comment: you have controls in form or you have a user control inside form and conrols in it?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I have controls in my form, this is just a form load, i don't have any codes in my form rather than in my form_load..

Comment: @EhsanSajjad And by the way my textboxes, datetimepickers and comboboxes are in a Tab Control Panel, will this affect that code?

Comment: @eljon_i3 then you have to do recursivley see the link i posted in my answer , the above code will work if controls are directly in form

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I don't get how can I do it recursively, but I guess the link would help me.. Can you have an example maybe?

Comment: @eljon_i3 it was wrong link connected check now this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button