# Access to the Ok/Accept Or Cancel Button of a RepositoryItemTimeSpanEdit?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I need to know if there is a way to access to the events of the buttons inside a `RepositoryItemTimeSpanEdit`.
Image to see the buttons I need the events for: Click
[Image](http://imageshack.com/a/img540/2497/VyTSxI.png)

I have tried to access in the `PopUp` event and `QueryPopUp`, however I can't get the button in any way yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this form through `Form.OwnedForms` property in `Popup` event. The type of this form is `DevExpress.XtraEditors.Popup.TimeSpanEditDropDownForm`, so you need just to find the form of this type. After that you can access buttons by using `TimeSpanEditDropDownForm.OkButton` property and `TimeSpanEditDropDownForm.CloseButton` property.
Here is example:

```
private void repositoryItemTimeSpanEdit1_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var popupForm = (TimeSpanEditDropDownForm)OwnedForms.FirstOrDefault(item => item is TimeSpanEditDropDownForm);

    if (popupForm == null)
        return;

    popupForm.OkButton.Click += OkButton_Click;
    popupForm.CloseButton.Click += CloseButton_Click;
}

private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ok");
}

private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
}
```

Comment: Thank, this works, but how can I interact with the current value of the `TimeSpanEdit`? I mean, how can I get the value in this event `OkButton_Click`

Comment: @Thorin Unfortunately, I have no developer tools right now, so now I can suggest you to iterate through `popupForm.Controls` collection to find out the control with `TimeSpanEdit` type. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/1805640) is the example of how to find the control of specific type. In `OkButton_Click` event you can get the `popupForm` by the same way through `Form.OwnedForms` property.