# Compare current value to all text blocks on form?

Tags: c#

I have multiple text blocks I want to compare the text values of with whatever the current random value is in my array, so I can "gray out" the text block when it gets "opened".

This code works for 1 text block, but I was wondering how I could do it for all 26 of my blocks w/o having to type out each one? Is there a way I can reference all my blocks, kind of like using the same click event for all my buttons?

```
if (money[turns]==Convert.ToInt32(tb0.Text))
                    {
                        tb0.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
                    }
```

Comment: Why don't you loop through all your `TextBox`es doing this validation? You have them in the `Controls` property of the form, just check its type to make sure it's the one you are interested in.

Comment: What is the application type? Forms? WPF?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. When you need to do this, it's almost always a design smell. You should use data binding, or the tag or name to identify which control displays what. Anyway "[your UI framework] find all controls" will yield plenty of results.

Comment: Sorry! WPF is the application type. The list solution worked perfectly for me and what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As addition to Alexei, if you want only compare specific TextBlock, first you can insert your `TextBlock` into a List

```
List<TextBlock> listTextBlock = new List<TextBlock>();
list.Add(tb0);
list.Add(tb1);
```

... so you just using loop to check each `TextBlock`.

```
foreach(TextBlock item in listTextBlock)
{
   if (money[turns]==Convert.ToInt32(item.Text))
   {
      item.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `Windows.Forms` you can iterate [through all your controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button) of type `TextBox` and compare your text to the one in each TextBox. The code should like this:

```
bool exists = GetAll(this, typeof(TextBox)).Any(t => t.Text.Equals(yourText));
```

As already suggested, it would be better to use databinding and do the search in your objects, rather than into your interface.