# C# - Find a control by one of the properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a number of controls that are derived from base controls. As part of these extended controls I have added a number of properties. One of these properties is a unique ID that helps me to bind it to a database value.

I need to be able to search for this control by UniqueID, a property that only my derived controls have (note that all controls on the form are my derived controls, and all of them have UniqueID as a property). Reflection jumps to mind but I cannot find an example.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Enumerable.OfType<T>` to filter out controls of your specific type and then you can query against the specific property, something like:

```
var controls = this.Controls.OfType<YourControl>().Where(r => r.UniqueId == someValue);
```

Remember this only searches the controls at root level, if you are interested in finding nested controls then you have to use a recursive approach. See: [How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Comment: Good Answer. How does it vary if each of the controls is different? For example, if I have a MyTextBox : TextBox and MyComboBox : ComboBox. Would I need to use Controls.OfType<Control>() ?

Comment: Sure you can use the base class in that case, but If you use `Control` base class then it will not be limited to the classes you specified above, it will include other control classes as well, like Button etc.

Comment: That's actually Ok. The only controls on there are the ones I have created, all of which contain the property. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: After testing this I have a Compile Time error, due to the fact that Control does not have the property I'm looking for. Since the controls don't derive from the same place, is there an alternative?

Comment: @RyanHargreaves, if the controls do not derive from the same place, then you probably have to resort to reflection.

Comment: Do you have an example of that?

Comment: One option would be to create your own BaseControl class derived from `Control` that has the UniqueID property and then derive all of your other controls from that class.  Then you could use `Enumerable.OfType<BaseControl>` and the property would always be there.  Then you wouldn't have to resort to reflection.

Comment: Better than using a common base class is defining an interface `IControlWithUniqueID`. Then have all your My* control classes implement that interface. You can then use `OfType<IControlWithUniqueID>()` as used in the answer.