# To focus or not to focus

Tags: c#, focus

I have a `Panel` that has `AutoScroll = true`.

In that `Panel` is a series of `TextBox`es. I should note that the `TextBox`es aren't on the `panel` directly but are nested several levels (about 4-5).

Now, the scrolling with my mouse wheel works only if the panel has focus, naturally. I can use `Focus()` within `mouseEnter` event to make sure the panel has focus.

However, the `TextBox`es I mentioned earlier rely heavily on focus. Only the user should be able to remove focus from the `TextBox` by clicking somewhere else.

The `TextBox`es are created dynamically and would make for a very messy code to keep an array of them, or any type of reference to check if they have focus. Not to mention that there could be a lot of them.

How do I give the focus to the `Panel`, but only if none of the `TextBox`es is focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep an array of the dynamically created Textboxes, you can get the array using:

```
bool anyTextBoxFocused = false;
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
  if (x is TextBox && x.Focused)
  {
       anyTextBoxFocused = true;
       break;
  }
}
if (!anyTextBoxFocused)
{
    //give focus to your panel
}
```

**Edit**

Based on [How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button), even nested controls can be obtained using:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control,Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl,type))
                              .Concat(controls)
                              .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

then use it with:

var c = GetAll(this,typeof(TextBox));

Comment: Problem is that Textboxes aren't on the control, but are nested a few layers (4-5) down. Btw, it's `x.Focused()`, and I would add `break;` after `anyTextBoxFocused = true;`.

Comment: Changed, thanks for spotting the Focused, added a break, and also hopefully provided help on how you can get even nested Textboxes.

Comment: I managed to find clean way of keeping the references. But your answer is what I would have done if I didn't.

Comment: If I may ask, what is the clean way you found? Did you declare a global array of textboxes and add to it every time you created a new one? Call it programmer's curiosity :)

Comment: There was a spot in my class where I was adding TextBoxes parents to the panel. I added the parents to a list and used the list to go through them.