# Creating a search bar within my program

Tags: .net

In Visual Basic on Visual Studio 2015, how would I create a search function that could look through multiple labels to find a specific word or phrase?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. Creating a textbox for the user (the searchbar) and finding text (where and how?) are two separate tasks.

Comment: I know how to create a textbox, I would like to know how to get the program to find specific words or phrases (input into the textbox) within a label on any form in my program when a button is pressed.

Comment: So basically you need a way to get a collection of all labels and then you can loop them in order to compare each text with the user input. If you are talking about WinForms, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button