# Panel control with variable name

Tags: c#, variables, panels

I have 25 panel control (Visible false).
I want to make it visible.

But it doesn' work:
(Error  1   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Visible' and no extension method 'Visible' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    string panelID = "panel" + i.ToString();
    panelID.Visible = true;
}
```

Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong in so many fronts.

As it is, what you're doing is creating 25 strings with values `panel0`, `panel1`, `panel2` etc., and trying to assign a value to a property of it. But strings don't contain a property named `Visible`, so obviously you'll get an error.

What you want to do is get hold of controls of type `Panel` in your form, and set their values.

```
foreach(var panel in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{
    panel.Visible = true;
}
```

Caveat: the above will only find `Panel` controls in your topmost form. If there are controls that are nested, you'd want to perhaps write a method to recursively find them. Above is just to give you the idea.

In addition, if you have multiple `Panel` controls and if you only want to set the property of those panels names fit your naming convention you can filter them out.

```
foreach(var panel in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{
    if( panel name fits your naming convention)
        panel.Visible = true;
}
```

Here, you can look for correct panel name by using a `Regex`, use a custom function etc.

Comment: 25 is example. In my code it is variable. Some times I want to make visible 4 panels some times 25 (25 it's max)

Comment: Yeah, so please do follow my lead. It will help you in the right direction.

Comment: Because, as I mentioned, it grabs all the top level controls of the type you specify. If you want controls inside controls, you can use a [method like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button).

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the dynamically created Panels to a collection from which you can refer them by their Name. One such collection is Dictionary.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<string, Panel> panels = new Dictionary< string, Panel>();
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; I++)
        {
             Panel panel = new Panel();
             panel.Name = "panel" + i.ToString();
             this.Controls.Add(panel);
             panels.Add(panel.Name, Panel);
         }
     }
}
```

now you can make them visible /invisible as following.

```
private void ShowHidePanel(int panelNumber, bool visible)
{
    panels["panel"+panelNumber.ToString()].Visible = visible ;
}
```

or if you want to show or hide all the panels you can do as following.

```
private void ShowHidePanels(bool visible)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
         panels["panel" + i.ToString()].Visible = visible;
    }
}
```