# Get all combobox names VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I am trying to loop through all the combo-boxes on my windows form VB.net application.

I had assumed this would work

```
Array.ForEach(Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox).Items.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(i).Name)))
```

but I can not refer to the items it seems to not know it is a combobo at that point

I am trying to get a list of all my combobox names so i can hopefully use that list of names in a loop to add items and read the selected index but my list of names is always blank. I am using the following code just trying to send the list to a messgebox to see if it is grabbing any names.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim allComboBoxValues As String = ""
    Dim c As Control
    Dim childc As Control
    For Each c In Me.Controls
        For Each childc In c.Controls
            If TypeOf childc Is ComboBox Then
                allComboBoxValues &= CType(childc, ComboBox).Text & ","
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox(allComboBoxValues)

    If allComboBoxValues <> "" Then
        MsgBox(allComboBoxValues)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could just create an array of CBOs so you dont have to go looking for them each time

Comment: what´s the container for the combos, a panel, a gridview?

Comment: You can have multiple depths of containers, so without recursion, I think this solution will not work. The current posted answer is the cleanest I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bellow `function` can be used to retrieved all child `Controls` of a certain type.

```
Private Function GetAll(Control As Control, Type As Type) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
        Dim Controls = Control.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
        Return Controls.SelectMany(Function(x) GetAll(x, Type)).Concat(Controls).Where(Function(y) y.GetType = Type)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
GetAll(Me, GetType(Combobox))
```

For your needs:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Values As String = String.Empty
    For Each ComboBox As ComboBox In GetAll(Me, GetType(ComboBox))
        Values &= ComboBox.Text & ","
    Next
    MsgBox(Values)
End Sub
```

([Function retrieved from this answer and converted to vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button))

Answer (score 0):

I use this Extension method. It uses generics which is quite clean. As mentioned in comments, recursion is a necessity.

```
Public Module ExtensionMethods

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim result As New List(Of T)
        For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(CType(ctrl, T))
            result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of T)())
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

Usage in your scenario:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim myCombos = Me.ChildControls(Of ComboBox)
    Dim allComboBoxValues = String.Join(", ", myCombos.Select(Function(c) c.Text))
    If myCombos.Any() Then
        MsgBox(allComboBoxValues)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! this way of doing this will be helpful in other parts of this application.