# Dynamically update labels

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I dynamically update the text of labels in a form so their text is numbered, in order, from 1 to 25?

In pseudo code, something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
    label + 'i'.Text = "i";
}
```

Comment: Array/List of Labels?

Comment: so you have 25 labels named Label1, Label2 etc. and you want to loop through them, setting their text to their numeric suffix?

Comment: Yeah, I guess an array will do the trick. Thaks!!!

Comment: @FrancescoB. Yeah, exactly

Comment: and you are using winforms, right?

Comment: @FrancescoB. Yes

Comment: `var label = this.Controls["Label" + i.ToString()] as Label;` inside your loop. Or if you want to shorten it up to one line: `(this.Controls["Label" + i.ToString()] as Label)?.Text = "i";`

Comment: @JohnCapibara I edited my answer to include a few more ideas. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting members of a class dynamically requires reflection. Something like this should do what you want. You will need to adjust it based on how the fields are declared.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    var property = this.GetType().GetProperty("label" + i);
    var label = (Label)property.GetValue(this);
    label.Text = "Label " + i;
}
```

Comment: *"Getting members of a class dynamically requires reflection."* No, it does not. Every control you add to a Windows Form is available in the `.Controls` collection, and is indexable by name, so you can replace all your reflection code with `var label = Controls["label" + i];`

Comment: In this case, yes, you are correct. However, generally you would need to use reflection to get a member in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this (tested):

```
foreach (var label in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    label.Text = label.Name.Replace("label", "");
}
```

Since you don't need to fill all label text in order, you can just loop through them and replace the "label" text.
The assumptions are those you made, i.e. all labels are named "label1", "label2" etc., plus the fact that all labels are inside a common control (a panel) or the window itself, which is what I did.

---

**EDIT: ADDITIONAL IDEAS**

The solution above works but, to make things more interesting, you might add a method to prevent dealing with labels that do not respect your naming convention (i.e. "label" followed by a number):

```
foreach (var label in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    if (RespectsNamingConvention(label.Name))
    {
        label.Text = label.Name.Replace("label", "");
    }
}
```

where you have

```
private bool RespectsNamingConvention(string name)
{
    var Suffix = name.Replace("label", "");
    return 
        name.StartsWith("label") &&
        Suffix.Count() > 0 &&
        Suffix.Where(e => !Char.IsDigit(e)).Count() == 0;
}
```

i.e. you check whether your label name starts with "label", is followed by something, which contains just digits.

Another improvement could be getting all labels in your window, even if they're not in the same control.

Which can be done like shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button).

Comment: @GrantWinney thank you. Perhaps my first answer was too concise, or maybe the downvoter wanted to "punish" an answer to a question he didn't deem worth. Best regards.