# C# Fill an array with all the buttons being used in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to fill an array with all the `Button`s being used in `Form1`.

```
Button[] ButtonArray = new Button[5];

ButtonArray[0] = button1;   
ButtonArray[1] = button2;   
ButtonArray[2] = button3;   
ButtonArray[3] = button4;   
ButtonArray[4] = button5;
```

This code works fine.
But if I have for example **100** buttons it is a long procedure.

Comment: If you have a design with 100 buttons then you should redesign it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Answer (score 17):

If all the `Button`s are on the form you can try using *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

Button[] ButtonArray = Controls
  .OfType<Button>()
  .ToArray();
```

**Edit**: in case you have some buttons within *groupboxes*, *panels* (i.e. not *directly* on the form, but on some kind of *container*), you have to elaborate the code into something like this

```
private static IEnumerable<Button> GetAllButtons(Control control) {
  IEnumerable<Control> controls = control.Controls.OfType<Control>();

  return controls
    .OfType<Button>()
    .Concat<Button>(controls
       .SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllButtons(ctrl)));
}

...

Button[] ButtonArray = GetAllButtons(this).ToArray();
```

See [How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button) for details

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted :)

Comment: Just note that `OfType` doesn't search recursively, so if a button is in a panel or groupbox or any other container control, it is not found.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: So how do you then access the buttons in a panel?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this one:

```
ButtonArray[] buttonArray = new ButtonArray[this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Count()]
int i =0; //index for button array
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()) //Iterate through each button control
{
    buttonArray [i++] = button;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to know how many buttons there were to start with though - Dmitry's approach doesn't require that.

Comment: I agreed to Dmitry's approach(elegant approach), but for newbies this can be more readable

Comment: you could simplify it by using unary operator inside of indexer `ButtonArray[i++]`

Comment: @Fabjan, Thanks for suggestions, I updated my answer

Comment: So how do you proposal initializing `ButtonArray` here? You haven't shown that, and it's pretty important.

Comment: That won't currently compile - it would have to be `Count()` rather than `Count`, and at this point I really don't think it's more readable than the `ToArray` answer. If someone needs to understand the `Count()` extension method to read the code, why wouldn't they understand the `ToArray()` extension method?

Comment: @DaisyShipton, I agreed to your point, now It seems pretty complected than the solution suggested by Dmitry

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerable.OfType` doesn't search controls down the control-hierarchy. So if you want to find controls recursively you could use this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RecursiveControlsOfType<T>(this Control rootControl) where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control child in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        if (child is T targetControl)
            yield return targetControl;
        foreach (T targetControlChild in child.RecursiveControlsOfType<T>())
            yield return targetControlChild;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Button[] nonRecursiveButtons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
Button[] recursiveButtons = this.RecursiveControlsOfType<Button>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Button> Buttons = new List<Button>();
foreach (var item in this.Controls) // Looping through all controls in the form
{
    if (item is Button) // if the current is a button we add it
    {
        Buttons.Add(item as Button);
    }
}
```