# How to find a control from controls of controls collection recursively?

Tags: c#, winforms

My control "**MyTextBox1**" add dynamically on form1 under container1 control. This form1 can be child of form2 and form2 can be child of form3 and so on how can I find my control from multi controls collection?

e.g. **MyTextBox1** exists in

> form3.form2.form1.Container1.MyTextBox1

how to find my control by name from multi control collections?

I do not want to use recursive foreach control collection. I am looking for an smart/short code like controls.Find().

Comment: Most have a `Controls` property, but it's not always that easy: Take `SplitContainer` for example, which has `Panel1` and `Panel2` instead.

Comment: _I do not want to use recursive foreach control collection._ - ultimately that's what you will end up doing. You have to search the root control's control collection and then for each control in that collection search it's children until you find what you are looking for or have no more controls to search for. You could easily encapsulate it in a helper function or even an extension method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button

Comment: Probably the easier solution might be, since you are adding the control dynamically, to just _keep the reference to the control you are adding_ somewhere. Then you won't have to find it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Comment: Probably a XY question. How exactly do you "dynamically" add your control? You should be more specific about that and include an example. it seems you don't keep track of the added control and then try to find it by name instead.

Comment: Well, do use Controls.Find().  Pass *true* for the searchAllChildren argument.  If you get nothing then that control does not have the Name property you expect, that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to put it *recoursive*, you can try *BFS* (Breadth First Search); let's implement it as an *extension method*:

```
public static class ControlExtensions { 
  public static IEnumerable<Control> RecoursiveControls(this Control parent) {
    if (null == parent)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));

    Queue<Control> agenda = new Queue<Control>(parent.Controls.OfType<Control>());

    while (agenda.Any()) {
      yield return agenda.Peek();

      foreach (var item in agenda.Dequeue().Controls.OfType<Control>())
        agenda.Enqueue(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
// Let's find Button "MyButton1" somewhere on MyForm 
// (not necessary directly, but may be on some container)
Button myBytton = MyForm
  .RecoursiveControls()
  .OfType<Button>()
  .FirstOrDefault(btn => btn.Name == "MyButton1");
```

Comment: thanks for answer. there are some controls do not have controls-collection instead have a Controls property, like SplitContainer  which has Panel1 and Panel2 and these panels have child controls. in that case above code does not work. can we cover this gap in your code please?

Comment: @Haseeb: I've tried the code over a `Button` on a `Panel` which is on `SplitContainer`; it does work. Actually `SplitContainer` being a `Control` has `Controls` property.

Comment: Many thanks let me check i will test and post my feedback comments here