# Change all buttons background color by equation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a class named **`Design`**

contain this codes

```
public static void Edit(Form frm, Color bkColor, Color btnColor,Color pnlColor)
{
    frm.BackColor = bkColor;
    frm.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
    frm.RightToLeftLayout = true;
    foreach (Button btn in frm.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        btn.BackColor = btnColor;
    }
    foreach (Panel pnl in frm.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        pnl.BackColor = pnlColor;
    }
}
```

and I am calling it by this in the form:

```
Design.Edit(this, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Yellow);
```

NOW it works good on the form background BUT on the panel and buttons not working at all

Comment: Controls are organized in a tree structure, always best visited with a recursive method.  Googling "windows forms recursively visit all controls" provides you with good hits.

Comment: `BackColor` is an ambient property. You don't need to change `BackColor` of all controls, changing back color of the form would be enough. Same for `RightToLeft` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recoursive search of your control inside of all the controls of the form.
Look [that accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button) that implement a very good recoursive approach.

Doing this:

```
frm.Controls.OfType<Button>()
```

you search only in the first layer of controls of your forms, so if you've a button inside a panel or another element (the 99,999999% of the situations) your foreach cannot find it.

adapting the Accepted answer at your Question:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(this Control control,Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => ctrl.GetAll(type))
                              .Concat(controls)
                              .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

[...]

```
foreach (Button btn in frm.GetAll(typeof(Button)))
    {
        btn.BackColor = btnColor;
    }
```

L-