# Search for controls. C#, WinForms, UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, search

I am currently working on a search box that find components. Example you type `Save Client` and it will then filter out all other components (Set their visibility to false) and only show the Save client button. I currently have over 60 odd buttons and other components labels, comboboxes etc. I am stuck big time and have no idea on how to achieve this feature. I have looked into Find Controls but the findings wasn't what I am looking for. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to get all controls on your form? If yes, then that's half of your feature. The other half is to decide which properties to inspect during search. A naive approach would just check the type of control and then (e. g. for a `Label`) look in the `.Text` property.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I was thinking about doing something like this: 

`private Control FindControl(Control parent, string name)
        {
            if (parent.Name == name) return parent;
            foreach (Control ctl in parent.Controls)
            {
                Control found = FindControl(ctl, name);
                if (found != null) return found;
            }

            return null;
        }`

Comment: Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/11683) and replace the `.Where(c => c.GetType() == type)` with `.Where(c => c.Name == name)`.

Comment: Thank you, with this I have something I can work with and a step in the right direction.