# How to get a list of my own created USERCONTROLs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have created two UserControls in my WinFroms Application. Some more UserControls will be created.

Now I want to get a list of my created UserControls by name.

For example:

> UserControl ctrl1
>
> UserControl ctrl2
>
> UserControl ctrl3

The UserControls are created like this:

```
namespace Test.Controlls
{
    public partial class ctrl1 : UserControl
    {
```

On my WinForms Application it will be included like this:

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            contrctrl1.Visible = true;
            contrctrl1.BringToFront();
```

Now I want ot get the names ctrl1, ctrl2 and ctrl3 in a list to loop through it afterwards.

Something like this:

```
List<> ctrllist = new List<>();
ctrllist.Add();

for (int i =0; <ctrllist>.count; i++)
{ 
   switch (ctrllist.toString())
   {
     case "ctrl1": //do seomething
               break;
     case "ctrl2": //do seomething
               break;
     case "ctrl2": //do seomething
               break;
   }    
}
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Thank you.

EDIT: I don't want to know textbox, button controls etc. I have created by own UserControl "Form" and want to store these Names in a list or datatable to retreive back the names if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all controls will be part of your `mainform` control you can get all children of that and loop through that.

Accesing `Mainform.Controls` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netframework-4.8)) likely wont be enough, you need to dig deeper. check this question on how to do that:

[How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Comment: I don't want to know textbox, button controls etc. I have created by own UserControl "Form" and whant to store these Names in a list or datatable to retreive back the names if needed.

Comment: okay, well what sets them apart from other controls? how are you going to find them?

Comment: Understood, but how can I get the name of the control form the list? Ctrl1.name or ctrl.text doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to traverse all custom controls `ctrl1`, you can refer to the following code.

```
List<ctrl1> ctrl1s = new List<ctrl1>();

private void btnGetAllCtrl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is ctrl1)
        {
            ctrl1s.Add((ctrl1)control);
        }
    }
}
```

And then traverse the ctrl1 list.

```
private void btnTraverse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ctrl1 c in ctrl1s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
    }
}
```