# Foreach control in form including children

Tags: c#, winforms

i am currently using this loop to translate my winforms program to different languages using google translate api:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            //translate labels, buttons and tabpages for now...
            if(c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
            {
                string old = c.Text;
                c.Text = TranslateTextToCustomLanguage(c.Text, currentLanguageCode, languageCode);
                Console.WriteLine("successfully translated " + old + " to " + c.Text);
            }
            else if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                string old = c.Text;
                c.Text = TranslateTextToCustomLanguage(c.Text, currentLanguageCode, languageCode);
                Console.WriteLine("successfully translated " + old + " to " + c.Text);
            }
            else if (c.GetType() == typeof(TabPage))
            {
                string old = c.Text;
                c.Text = TranslateTextToCustomLanguage(c.Text, currentLanguageCode, languageCode);
                Console.WriteLine("successfully translated " + old + " to " + c.Text);
            }
            
        }
```

but this loop does not include controls in panels and tabpages

can i make a loop that also includes all the children?

Comment: Just recurse over the controls property

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/284240 To find all just remove the type check and then loop them with your `foreach`-loop#.

Comment: thx bro but i have to type more