# "foreach" loop for each object of a certain type within a window

Tags: c#

I have 10 SpinEdit objects inside a Window that have a minimum value and a maximum value.
At the click event of a button I need to check if even one of these objects exceeds the range.
Currently I created the following function but I have to call it individually for each object:

```cs
public bool SpinEditValueOK(decimal Value, decimal MinValue, decimal MaxValue)
{
    if (Value > MinValue && Value < MaxValue) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

Is it possible to do a “foreach” loop to parameterize the SpinEdit objects?

Comment: What framework are you using? Windows Forms? WPF? For WPF [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type) may be helpful.  And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button) is similar for  Windows Forms

Comment: Provide more details like type of "Window". Are you using WPF and DevExpress library ?

Comment: You could put them into a list yourself, and then iterate over that list

Comment: Check if there is any built in Min/Max values on the control.  If there is no min/max there might be an event handler so you can do validation each time the value is changed. You typically want to validate values as early as possible, not delay it until the user presses some button.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a way to iterate through all controls on a form. This is not trivial, as controls can be nested, but the `Controls` collection of the Form only contains the top-level controls.

You can use this recursive extension method to iterate all the controls:

```cs
public static class WinFormsExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> Descendants(this Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls) {
            yield return c;
            foreach (Control child in c.Descendants()) {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can check the `SpinEdit` controls like this:

```cs
public bool SpinEditValuesOK()
{
    return this.Descendants()
        .OfType<SpinEdit>()
        .All(c => c.Value >= c.MinValue && c.Value <= c.MaxValue);
}
```

Where I assume that this code is in the form and `this` stands for the Form.

I also assume that `MinValue` and `MaxValue` are inclusive. Therefore the `>=` and `<=` instead of `<` and `>`. But I am not sure whether DevExpress' `SpinEdit` does allow values to exceed the bounds given by Min/MaxValue. So, this check might be superfluous after all.