# Enumerate all controls in the form

Tags: .net, asp.net

```
private void EnableControls(bool enable)
        {
            foreach (TextBox t in Page.Form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                t.ReadOnly = !enable;
            }
            chkSameAsCurrent.Enabled = enable;
        }
```

The above code runs fine in a simple page not having any master page, but if I run it in a ContentPage I can not enumerate the TextBoxes and not even any control in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I think this should work.

```
 private void RecursiveLoopThroughControls(Control root)
 {
      foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
      {
          RecursiveLoopThroughControls(control);
          //process the control.
      }
 }
```

Call the method using

```
 RecursiveLoopThroughControls(Page)
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should do this through [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). Try this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253937/recursive-control-search-with-linq).
If you want to enumerate Master Page controls - follow them in `Page.Master`