# Having Trouble Using LINQ to Objects on the Controls Collection of a Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to store data from a form for recovery from the session.
Below is my rough first attempt for a generalized method for textboxes:

Load Session:

```
Dictionary<string, string> AppInfo = (Dictionary<string,string>) Session["ApplicantionInfo"];
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
         .ToList<TextBox>()
         .ForEach( x => x.Text = AppInfo[x.ID] );
```

Save Session:

```
Session["ApplicationInfo"] = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                  .ToList<TextBox>()
                                  .ToDictionary<TextBox,string>(kvp => kvp.ID);
```

However, it appears that the Controls collection is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

`this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` yields no results at run time when I do a quick watch on it.

Comment: Are any of the TextBox controls contained inside other controls?  If so, they won't be found directly in the Controls collection for the page.

Comment: Is there any easy way to get an enumeration of controls if the above is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Recursive control search with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253937/recursive-control-search-with-linq).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I access form controls.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
{
      this.Controls[i].Visible = false;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
public static List<Control> GetAllControls(List<Control> controls, Type t, Control parent)
{
            foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType()== t)
                    controls.Add(c);
                if (c.HasControls())
                    controls = GetAllControls(controls, t, c);
            }
            return controls;
}
```

and call

```
var allControls = new List<Control>();
GetAllControls(allControls, typeof(TextBox), Page);
```