# How Can I Get The Button Controls in Windows Form - Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Get All the Buttons In A Form including 
the buttons in the panel of the same form..

Comment: your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-winform-of-a-specific-type-button-textbox

Comment: You can also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253937/recursive-control-search-with-linq

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 List<Control> list = new List<Control>();

            GetAllControl(this, list);

            foreach (Control control in list)
            {
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    //all btn
                }
            }

        private void GetAllControl(Control c , List<Control> list)
        {
            foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
            {
                list.Add(control);

                if (control.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
                    GetAllControl(control , list);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I have done,
I wrote a simple function, when I click a Button, I Select Only the Panel Control and pass it to a function for further loop through the control on that panel.

```
private void cmdfind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
                    //AddToList((Panel)control); //this function pass the panel object so further processing can be done 
            }                         
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
   if (control.GetType()== typeof(Button))
   {

       //do stuff with control in form
   }

   else if (control.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
   {
       var panel = control as Panel;
       foreach (var pan in panel.Controls)
       {
           if (pan.GetType() == typeof(Button))
           {

                //do stuff with control in panel
           }
        }
    }              

}
```

Comment: recursion can use  in case of Panel contains another panel with a button.