# asp.net convert asp.net page into Page variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load an ASP.NET 2.0 aspx page using System.Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376404/load-an-asp-net-2-0-aspx-page-using-system-reflection)

In the following code, I iterate through my project and get file paths for .aspx pages. How do cast them to Page variable. I have tried the following code but its not working. I get the following error message

```
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Web.UI.Page'.
```

Please help me.

thanks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string filepath in filePaths)
    {
        if (filepath.EndsWith(".aspx"))
        {
            Response.Write(filepath + "<br/>");

            Page page = (Page)Convert.ChangeType(filepath, typeof(Page));

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Why is it down voted? I looked through google and SO for 30 minutes and could not get an asnwer. this is very arrogant. I am really trying to find an answer here.

Comment: Arrogant is bit strong don't you think? I posted the link in comment above, which is EXACTLY what you need.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner: although I didn't vote to close, the most likely reason is that you haven't explained what it is you are really trying to do.  Due to the code you listed there are multiple potential solutions, some of which are fairly complicated and might be overkill.  As Tim asked: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Tomas, thank you for your link. It helped me 100%. Very much appreciate it. I am trying to go through all the pages in the project and identify Label and Button control through each page. Thanks again.

Comment: Chris is it possible to remove the down vote? thanks

Comment: You are trying to convert a `string` to `Page`? you must be GOD to do so.

Comment: Quantic, you have a better idea?

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner: only the person(s) who downvoted can remove it...

Comment: Also, you might consider just closing / deleting this question.  Your other one is a dupe and overrides this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your last comment "I am trying to go through all the pages in the project and identify Label and Button control through each page.". So I think what you need is this:

1. Make some base class from which all pages inherit
2. Put some logic in that base class (probably override PreRender, it is not clear what you want to do with controls) and find all controls (Label and Button) on those pages (you probably need to implement custom FindControl method, because [FindControl in ASP.NET is not recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574686/313199)).

That is much better and cleaner than what you are trying to achieve with loading .aspx directly etc.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback.. but this does not work for what I am doing. I wish I could get an answer purely from technical point of view with out having to disclose all the nitty gritty details on what I am doing. SO forum is very much becoming a very difficult place to have a free flowing discussions.