# How to get the href from LiteralControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I need to read the href from a `LiteralControl` and add some attributes to it:

Markup;

```
<a id="aMyAnchor" runat="server" href="bob.com">click me</a>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
string url= "bob.com";
var myAnchor = divLinkContainer.Controls
    .Cast<LiteralControl>()
    .Where(a => a.Attributes["href"]
    .Contains(url)).First();
```

However, `LiteralControl` does not have an attributes property...

**NOTE: I know I can access the link directly via its id, but that's just because I made the example code simple.**

**EDIT:**

This:

```
string url= "bob.com";
var myAnchor = divLinkContainer.Controls
    .Cast<HtmlAnchor>()
    .Where(a => a.HRef
    .Contains(url)).First();
```

results in this:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type
>   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor'.

Comment: I don't aks why you aren't using a Hyperlink instead, because you're accessing it on serverside anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myAnchor = divLinkContainer.Controls
    .Cast<Control>()
    .Where(a => a is HtmlAnchor).Select(a=>(HtmlAnchor)a)
    .Where(a => a.HRef.Contains(url))
    .First();
```

The idea is to use Cast with the most possible/relevant base class and also make sure all your controls which are going to be casted do inherit that type.

Comment: For some reason I get "sequence contains no elements" every time, even if I remove the .contains portion and I try to get all HtmlAnchors.  In the debugger they still show as LiteralControl.             var test = divLinkContainer.Controls
                .OfType<HtmlAnchor>();

Comment: If the anchors are not direct children of the divLinkContainer and you call First, then you get this exception. You'll need to find a method to get all descendants.

Comment: Oh, yes. Each anchor has p tag as its direct parent.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253937/recursive-control-search-with-linq  You answered my original question with the information I provided.

Answer (score 4):

Your `divLinkContainer` node may contain other nodes which cannot be casted to `HtmlAnchor` type. To select only nodes of type `HtmlAnchor` use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var myAnchor = divLinkContainer.Controls
    .OfType<HtmlAnchor>()
    .Where(a => a.HRef.Contains(url))
    .First();
```

Comment: @白ジェームス: this could be done even more cleaner: `divLinkContainer.Controls.OfType<HtmlAnchor>().First(a => a.HRef.Contains(url))` :p

Comment: ya, but I live in a 1024x768 world.  By the way, I always get "sequence contains no elements" for myAnchor.  Any idea why?  Even if I remove the where portion.

Comment: @白ジェームス: you get *sequence contains no elements* because `.First()` method expects the sequence is not empty. Use `.FirstOrDefault()` if you want to get `null` if no element found. Empty sequence means there is no elements matching your criteria.

Comment: I see.  I didn't realize it before, but my markup was oversimplified in the question.

Comment: @白ジェームス: why don't you access your anchor by it's id? It is really much more easier then doing it using LINQ. But it still could be done by using LINQ if you have exact the same markup as you posted in update to your question. If the *depth* of your anchor is really unknown the only solution I see is to iterate through all child node of the child nodes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to an [`HtmlAnchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ff86hxd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead, then you can use it's [`href`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.href.aspx) property.

Comment: I get an exception when I do that: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor'.

Comment: Maybe because you already have declared in as LiteralControl. Modify the `protected global::  System.Web.UI.LiteralContro aMyAnchor` to `protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor aMyAnchor` in the designer.cs. But actually a `a` is mapped to HtmlAnchor if it's `runat=server`.

Comment: Well, yes, of course.  However, I stubbornly asked when using a LiteralControl.  I'd like a solution using LiteralControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the required target object to the “[HtmlAnchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)” type and operate with the “[HRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.href%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)” property.

Answer (score 0):

Assign href to the value property of another control and make that control hidden.