# Looping through asp:CheckBox controls

Tags: asp.net

I have 11 of these controls on my page, all are checkboxes.  It is contained within a master page.

I can accomplish what I want like so:

```
generalInformation.InputAttributes.Add( "class", "SetupChecklist" );
generalInformation2.InputAttributes.Add( "class", "SetupChecklist" );
generalInformation3.InputAttributes.Add( "class", "SetupChecklist" );
```

Etc..

I am now trying to loop through these and do the same thing to save myself some code, but I am having a lot of trouble getting this to work properly, well I can't get it to work at all.

Can anyone give me a good way to loop through these 11 checkbox controls and add the css class SetupChecklist?

I tried this and it isn't adding the class for some reason.

```
protected void InitializeCheckboxes ()
    {
        //generalInformation.InputAttributes.Add( "class", "SetupChecklist" );
        var allCheckBoxes = Page.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
        foreach ( var c in allCheckBoxes )
        {
            c.InputAttributes.Add( "class", "SetupChecklist" );
        } 
    }
```

I go call `InitializeCheckboxes();` in the Page_Load method.  It does work when I just use generalInformation.InputAttribues.Add etc..  But not when I loop through them.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best would be to place them in a `Panel`(rendered as a div) or other container control. Then you can get the references with LINQ's [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
// assuming all checkboxes are in a panel named "SetupContainer"
var allCheckBoxes = SetupContainer.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
foreach(var chb in allCheckBoxes)
    chb.InputAttributes.Add( "class", "SetupChecklist" );
```

Of course you can also use it to find all CheckBoxes on the whole Page, but that might be prone to errors.

Comment: @JamesWilson: Actually that works only for the given container control and does not look recursively down into sub-containers(like GridView or FormView). If you really need to look down(what is not recommended since it's more error-prone and might be inefficient): http://stackoverflow.com/a/253962/284240

Comment: Alright, I added runat="server" to my content div, and then changes Page.Controls to checklistContent.Controls.  And it seems to be working just fine, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

not tested but may help you..

```
foreach(Control oControl in Page.Controls)
{
  if(oControl is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)oControl).ID.StartsWith("generalInformation") )
   ((CheckBox)oControl).InputAttributes.Add( "class", "SetupChecklist" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Checkbox will render like below due to `runat = "server"`.

```
<span class="SetupChecklist" class="SetupChecklist" name="generalInformation">
     <input id="generalInformation" type="checkbox" name="generalInformation" />
</span>
```

---

### JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").addClass('GuestClass');
    });
</script>
```

This will save your time for below steps.

> 1. From Client goes to
> 2. IIS Web Server
> 3. ISAPI Extension
> 4. ISAPI Extension loads/execute/converts  aspx to HTML
> 5. sends back to IIS Web Server.
> 6. IIS responds back to client

Comment: That is an alternate solution I could have used.  I did need to figure out how to loop through them anyway, as they will check a database to see if they should be checked or not.  But this solution would work for adding the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GetUserControls(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in controls)
    {
        if (ctl is CheckBoxOrWhateverControlTypeYouWant)
        {
             /// Add attribute
        }

        if (ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
            GetUserControls(ctl.Controls);
    }
}
```