# Generic method to get all controls of type T

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a method that returns a `List<T>` of child controls that looks like this:

```
void GetAllControlsOfType<T>(List<T> lst, Control parent) where T:class
{
    if (parent.GetType() == typeof(T))
        lst.Add(parent as T);

    foreach (Control ch in parent.Controls)
        this.GetAllControlsOfType<T>(lst, ch);
}
```

But I have to use it like this:

```
List<WebControl> foo = new List<WebControl>();
GetAllControlsOfType<WebControl>(foo, this); //this = webpage instance
```

Surely there is some c# magic that will allow me to write a method that I can call like this:

```
List<WebControl> foo = GetAllControlsOfType<WebControl>(this);
```

Comment: The first part of the answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253937/recursive-control-search-with-linq

Comment: The second part is equally relevant. Once you have all controls, use `OfType<T>()` to get the ones you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "magic" is simply declaring another method that returns the `List<T>` rather than `void`.

```
List<T> GetAllControlsOfType<T>(Control parent) where T : class {
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    GetAllControlsoFType<T>(list, parent);   // Invoke your existing method
    return list;
}
```

Because you're using recursion, you can't simply *modify* your existing method to return `List<T>`, since doing so would make it impossible for you to keep track of that list and build on it.

A few other minor points:

- You have:

  ```
  if (parent.GetType() == typeof(T))
  ```

  But it would be more clear to write it as:

  ```
  if (parent is T)
  ```

  Unless, of course, you truly want your method to *fail* when used with subclasses of `T`.
- You may want to consider declaring the new method as an extension method by making `parent` declared as `this Control parent` (provided it's declared in a static class)

  This would allow you to invoke the method as `this.GetAllControlsOfType<WebControl>()`