# How to count the number of user controls that I have in a page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a page that has 5 user controls. I want to do more with them, but for now, I just want to count them using the following method.

```
void btnFormSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int i = 0;
  ControlCollection collection = Page.Controls;
  foreach (Control ctr in collection)
  {
    if (ctr is UserControl)
    {
      i++;
    }
   }
}
```

When I debug this code, i = 1, and the control is the master page (I didn't know that the master page is a user control).

How do I count user controls that are on my page?

## EDIT

This is my content placeholder markup.

```
<asp:Content ID="cntMain" runat="Server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentMain">
```

Comment: _Why_ do you need to count the number of user controls?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Replacing my original, off-base answer with the following.

You probably need to recurse to controls within controls (perhaps into a Panel?).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4(v=vs.100).aspx

> This example finds only the controls contained in the Page object and
>   the controls that are direct children of the page. It does not find
>   text boxes that are children of a control that is in turn a child of
>   the page. For example, if you added a Panel control to page, the Panel
>   control would be a child of the HtmlForm control contained by the
>   Page, and it would be found in this example. However, if you then
>   added a TextBox control into the Panel control, the TextBox control
>   text would not be displayed by the example, because it is not a child
>   of the page or of a control that is a child of the page. A more
>   practical application of walking the controls this way would be to
>   create a recursive method that can be called to walk the Controls
>   collection of each control as it is encountered.

EDIT 2: Adding links to recursive control search examples on SO.

Example using LINQ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/253962/704808

Traditional example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955836/704808

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change where you look for:

```
void btnFormSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int i = 0;
  // here, look inside the form, and not on page.
  ControlCollection collection = Page.Form.Controls;
  foreach (Control ctr in collection)
  {
    if (ctr is UserControl)
    {
      i++;
    }
   }
}
```

I have tested and working for me.