# Unable to cast object of type 'item here' to type 'item here'

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

When I do something like:

```
For Each item As HScrollBar In Me.Controls 'ERROR: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.HScrollBar'.
item.Visible = False
Next
```

I get an error because I have a control on a windows forms that is not the item which is a hscrollbar.

Comment: Did you expect a different result? Which result did you expect?

Comment: I expected all the hscrollbars to not be visible.

Comment: Read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253937/recursive-control-search-with-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's not correct code.  Me.Controls contains controls, not just scrollbars.  Fix:

```
    For Each item As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf item Is HScrollBar Then
            '' etc..
        End If
    Next
```

Or the cleaner Linq version:

```
    For Each item As HScrollBar In Me.Controls.OfType(Of HScrollBar)()
        '' etc..
    Next
```